# Are there budget repositioning cruises from anywhere in East or Southeast Asia to Australia later in 2017?

Tags: budget, australia, cruising, southeast-asia, east-asia

Apparently not all repositionings of cruise ships are cruises and not all repositioning cruises are at budget travel prices, by which I mean a comparable price to a flight on a LCC airline.

But I would love to know if there is any repo cruise in this kind of budget range from SE or E Asia to Australia in 2017?

I believe there's no centralized place to look for these and that not all such cruises that might fit this question are even necessarily labelled as repo cruises.

This is a new kind of travel to me I just heard of the other day. If it's also new to you please see [the previous, introductory, question on the topic here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/what-exactly-are-repositioning-cruises).

Comment: Define "budget" :).

Comment: @Johns-305: I did: comparable to the price of an LCC flight. My friends here paid a few hundred euro for a transatlantic repo for example.

Comment: While your question is way too broad, and may be closed, a [quick google](http://www.repositioncruises.com/royal-caribbean-repositioning-cruises/) resulted in this site that may help you narrow your research to carriers with routes that may work.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that many cruises are priced based on double occupancy. Some ships may have (tiny) single cabins, but many do not. If you're traveling alone, you'll be paying considerably more.

Answer (score 8):

**No**, you're not going to find anything cost-competitive with LCCs, meaning a few hundred dollars.  (That would barely get you from Sydney to Brisbane.) You can count the number of SE Asia to Australia cruises per year on your fingers, and both markets consider the other exotic and desirable, so there's plenty of demand as well.

Random sample: Sydney to Singapore, 14 nights, bunk in windowless cellar shared with 4 people... $1929pp. https://m.ozcruising.com.au/detail/cruiseVY19APR17

Comment: Are you only addressing SE Asia? I'm also asking about E Asia: China, Japan, Taiwan, South Korea.

Comment: The sense I have is that a good chunk of the cruise ships in Asia are either doing the Chinese market thing (at which point they tend to go to China and stay there for the long haul) or they're on the luxury side of the market doing "world cruises" of the sort that will cost much more than your budget. Some ships will move seasonally between Seattle/Vancouver/Alaska and Australia (perhaps via Hawaii), which is more like what you're describing.

Comment: @hippietrail I'm not aware of any E Asia to Australia routes that don't pass through SE Asia (Vietnam, Thailand, Singapore, Philippines), which is geographically in the way.

Answer (score 7):

The great deals on repositioning cruises tend to be on routes with lots of time at sea and very little time sightseeing or in ports, ie trans-atlantic.  You can occasionally find deals on shakedown cruises as well, after a refurbished older ship comes out of dry dock and is heading back to its home port.

A repositioning operation between Asia and Australia has a bevy of potential interesting stops, so the cruise lines build an itinerary around them and make better revenue.  You actually would be hard pressed to find a "repositioning cruise" on that route, they would be sold at full price as an "Asia to Australia" sailing.

There are always exception,so you could look at ships sailing in Australia versus those that sail in SE Asia or East Asia, and find which do both.  Then look at what each ship offers during the transition period. (though I would hazard a guess Australia and SE Asia have the same cruise season?)